# Query SPARQL doesn't work with "dct:subject"

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

```
SELECT ?name ?birth  ?person ?subject 

WHERE {      ?person dbo:birthPlace :London .      ?person 

dbo:birthDate ?birth .      ?person foaf:name ?name .  

?person dct:subject :English_rock_singers. ?person dct:subject ?

subject.   } ORDER BY ?name
```

This query works only if I delete the "subject". 
Is there a way to query dbpedia with a category?

Comment: Is [this output](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%3Fname+%3Fbirth++%3Fperson+%3Fsubject%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthPlace+dbr%3ALondon+.%0D%0A%3Fperson+dbo%3AbirthDate+%3Fbirth+.%0D%0A%3Fperson+foaf%3Aname+%3Fname+.++%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Fperson+dct%3Asubject+dbc%3AEnglish_rock_singers.%0D%0A%3Fperson+dct%3Asubject+%3Fsubject.+++%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fname%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear, I think your problem is with formatting the query and defining the prefixes. This should work:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>

SELECT ?name ?birth ?person ?subject WHERE {

  ?person dbo:birthPlace dbr:London.
  ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth.    
  ?person foaf:name ?name.  
  ?person dct:subject dbc:English_rock_singers.  
  ?person dct:subject ?subject.   
} 
ORDER BY ?name
```